# Weird character after UTF8_encode

Tags: php, utf-8, encode, arabic

When I try to change from `windows-1256` to `utf8` text become like that

```
ÇáÑßä ÇáÚÇã ááãæÇÖíÚ ÇáÚÇãÉ
```

I'm trying to change the encoding of webpage I grabbed using `file_get_contents`.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know Arabic, this might point you in the right direction:

```
$str = 'ÇáÑßä ÇáÚÇã ááãæÇÖíÚ ÇáÚÇãÉ';
$str = iconv("windows-1256", "utf-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

```
$output = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", file_get_contents($url));
```

Since I can't know what your content is, you might have to try UTF-8//TRANSLIT and UTF-8//IGNORE